# How to create a UserControl from a string

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Is there a neat way to create a UserControl from a string?

I would like to avoid hard coding like this:

```
if (tool.ToolName == "Image_Tool") { ctl = new Image_Tool() as UserControl; }
```

Image_Tool is an existing UserControl.  ToolName is retrieved from parsing a folder to get the filename of the UserControl.

Would love to do something like this:

```
UserControl ctl = new tool.toolName() as UserControl
```

Is that "pie in the sky" thinking?  PHP has a way to convert a string to a variable...wondering if C# has some way to do that?

Thanks.

Hans, tried your suggestion but now getting TypeLoadException for this code:

```
  ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance("AutomationSystem", tool.ToolName);
            Object o = handle.Unwrap();
            ctl = o as UserControl;
```

This is a windows app not a web app so no dll exists, just the exe.

Comment: Use Activator.CreateInstance().  Don't forget the namespace name.

Comment: Hans, I have been trying different suggestions on the web for Activator.CreateInstance to no avail.  The way I do it above seems like it should work but I get the message that Image_Tool is not found in the assembly (tried null in place of "AutomationSystem" and it found current assembly).  Can't understand why Image_Tool is not found when I can assign a UserControl variable = new Image_Tool().  No code problems there...  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ask a colleague to look over your shoulder.  Non-zero odds he'll point his finger and exclaim "dude, you forgot the namespace name".

Answer (score 0):

So Hans was kind of right.  My namespace was in the wrong spot. Here's how I resolved this:

```
ObjectHandle handle = Activator.CreateInstance(null, "AutomationSystem.Toolbox."+tool.ToolName);
                Object o = handle.Unwrap();

                ctl = o as UserControl;
```